# Can I use fit() function with images in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, classification, keras, tensorflow, computer-vision

I want to use vgg16 to train a dataset that contains images.

Can I use `fit()` function instead of `fit_generator()` in Keras? How?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. `fit()` takes the images in a numpy matrix while `fit_generator()` takes a generator object (processing images in batch)

[Guide](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/) for using `fit()`.

[Guide](https://medium.com/@fromtheast/implement-fit-generator-in-keras-61aa2786ce98) for using `fit_generator`.

Comment: Can I convert the images to numpy matrix?

Comment: They are automatically stored as numpy matrix in almost all the libraries. http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/numpy_images.html